# Print resolution when Photoshop shows pixels per inch not dpi

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution

I am about to send some sketches which I have scanned and and tidied up in Photoshop.  My scans were 300dpi at the scanner.  I've checked by docs and they all say 300 pixels per inch.

Here's an example:

[image: photoshop settings showing resolution at 300 pixels per inch]

I tend to work for web, so don't do print stuff.

Am I on the right track?  Are the files big enough for print?  Please excuse my novice-ness.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

DPI and PPI are the same thing.

Technically pixels per inch refer to the pixels on a screen and dots per inch refer to the dots of ink on printed paper, but they are the same thing.